# Restricting AWS Cloudwatch Dashboard exclusive to some role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a use case to create a separate cloudwatch dashboard(or views) for admins and developers, can I restrict a user to view cloudwatch dashboard based on the user's assumed role ?
Is it something that AWS allows to configure a IAM access policy for each dashboard ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can not share/restrict access to a specific dashboard using roles/IAM.

When working with policies using CloudWatch we have the following:

- The **AdministratorAccess** policy that is able to see all dashboards
- The **CloudWatchFullAccess** policy that is also able to see all dashboards
- A custom policy that includes one or more of these specific permissions:

  - `cloudwatch:GetDashboard` and `cloudwatch:ListDashboards` to be able to view all dashboards
  - `cloudwatch:PutDashboard` to be able to create or modify dashboards
  - `cloudwatch:DeleteDashboards` to be able to delete dashboards

With these options we do not have the option to specify the access to a specific dashboard.

If you want to share the dashboard with specific users, we can do this sharing with their emails. To understand how to do this, check here: [Share a single dashboard with specific users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-dashboard-sharing.html#share-cloudwatch-dashboard-email-addresses)

Also, take a look on these pages:

- [Sharing CloudWatch dashboards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-dashboard-sharing.html)
- [Using Amazon CloudWatch dashboards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Dashboards.html)